# Exponential map on Diffeomorphism group of $S^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am reading Segal book on Loop groups, and he mentions the following theorem:

---

$$ \exp: Vect(S ^1) \rightarrow Diff(S ^1) $$

the map taking a vector field to the diffeomorphism obtained by flowing along it's flow for unit time, is neither locally one-one nor locally onto.

---

I find this highly non-trivial and though the book does give a proof I am having 
trouble understanding it.

(Am I interpreting the $\exp$ map wrong?)

For example, suppose I look at a diffeomorphism which does not move any point more than a small angle $\epsilon$, then I can give a canonical unit time homotopy from this diffeomorphism to identity which I could differentiate to get a vector field. Which seems to imply that the $\exp$ map is locally surjective. What am I getting wrong here?

Also he says that the map which rotates $S ^1$ by an angle of $2 \pi/n$ is hit more than once by $\exp$. One vector field is easy, the constant vector field $ 2 \pi / n \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} $ at each point. I am unable to concretely see any other vector field in the pre image.

Thanks,

Comment: For surjectivity, I guess, a reflection through any line can't arise by a flow. (What vectors would you put to the farest points from the axis of the reflection?)

Comment: Yes global surjectivity is not true, but the theorem only talks about local surjectivity. A reflection is not even in the connected component of the identity map. (May me I should edit the question and make it clearer that I mean local surjectivity.)

Comment: To answer your last question about injectivity, you can add multiples of $2\pi \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$ to the constant vector field you mention without changing the diffeomorphism obtained by flowing by unit time.

Comment: But this again only contradicts injectivity and not local injectivity. We can always restrict to say vector fields of length at the most $\pi$ and ask for injectivity here.